# How do I load this array into memory

Tags: objective-c, arrays, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults, nskeyedarchiver

I saved an array using the following code:

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myArray];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:@"myArray"];
```

What is the code to load it back into memory?

Comment: Merely accessing the array again does not load it into memory?

Comment: I'm talking about when the application starts up again. The array needs to be read in. The whole point of the above code is to write it to disk so that it can be read back in later.

Answer (score 0):

Put this where you need to load it, should work. You'll get back an immutable NSData object.

```
NSData *data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dataForKey:@"myArray"];
```